# If cell starts with__extract first 3 characters. If it starts with __ only extract 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good Morning,

I was wondering if there was a way to place a formula in Column F:

- If respective E Cell starts with AI, extract the first **three**
  characters in the F cell.
- If respective E Cell starts with anything else, extract only the first **two** characters in the F Cell.

[example of desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJEHH.jpg)

Any help you can provide will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cell starts with "AI" show first 3 chars of E Cell otherwise 2

> =LEFT(E1, IF(LEFT(E1,2) = "AI",3,2))

Answer (score 1):

You should always check that the string is long enough before extracting portions:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>2, LEFT(A1,2+N(LEFT(A1,2)="Al")),"too short")
```